# Issuses with Ubuntu software app. I is not loading

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies

I used the following command to fix the problem but it did not work.

`sudo apt install gnome-software`

I got many warnings. Please help me fixing this.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gnome-software-plugin-snap
Suggested packages:
  gnome-software-plugin-flatpak
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnome-software gnome-software-plugin-snap
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 965 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,079 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 gnome-software amd64 3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.0 [892 kB]
Get:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 gnome-software-plugin-snap amd64 3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.0 [72.9 kB]
Fetched 965 kB in 0s (2,439 kB/s)                    
Selecting previously unselected package gnome-software.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libctf0:amd64' missing; assuming pac
kage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libip4tc2:amd64' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libksba8:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'pinentry-curses' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libexpat1:amd64' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'bash' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'networkd-dispatcher' missing; assumi
ng package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtext-iconv-perl' missing; assumin
g package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gcc-9' missing; assuming package has
 no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtext-charwidth-perl' missing; ass
uming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'lsb-base' missing; assuming package 
has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libzstd1:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'manpages-dev' missing; assuming pack
age has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'adduser' missing; assuming package h
as no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-dbus' missing; assuming pack
age has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libapparmor1:amd64' missing; assumin
g package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpython3.8-minimal:amd64' missing;
 assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'apt' missing; assuming package has n
o files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'apt-utils' missing; assuming package
 has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgpm2:amd64' missing; assuming pac
kage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gpg-agent' missing; assuming package
 has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'perl-modules-5.30' missing; assuming
 package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mime-support' missing; assuming pack
age has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpam-modules:amd64' missing; assum
ing package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libstdc++-9-dev:amd64' missing; assu
ming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'bsdutils' missing; assuming package 
has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gpg-wks-client' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'grep' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblzma5:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgpg-error0:amd64' missing; assumi
ng package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libhogweed5:amd64' missing; assuming
 package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'xdg-user-dirs' missing; assuming pac
kage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'tar' missing; assuming package has n
o files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libmagic-mgc' missing; assuming pack
age has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libfile-fcntllock-perl' missing; ass
uming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libalgorithm-diff-perl' missing; ass
uming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libglib2.0-0:amd64' missing; assumin
g package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'manpages' missing; assuming package 
has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblz4-1:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libicu66:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libssl1.1:amd64' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libhx509-5-heimdal:amd64' missing; a
ssuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libargon2-1:amd64' missing; assuming
 package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libasn1-8-heimdal:amd64' missing; as
suming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpam-modules-bin' missing; assumin
g package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libreadline8:amd64' missing; assumin
g package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libc-bin' missing; assuming package 
has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsqlite3-0:amd64' missing; assumin
g package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gpgsm' missing; assuming package has
 no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsasl2-modules:amd64' missing; ass
uming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'ncurses-bin' missing; assuming packa
ge has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libffi7:amd64' missing; assuming pac
kage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libacl1:amd64' missing; assuming pac
kage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'binutils-common:amd64' missing; assu
ming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libmagic1:amd64' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libunistring2:amd64' missing; assumi
ng package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsmartcols1:amd64' missing; assumi
ng package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-libc-dev:amd64' missing; assum
ing package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libctf-nobfd0:amd64' missing; assumi
ng package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libldap-2.4-2:amd64' missing; assumi
ng package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgcrypt20:amd64' missing; assuming
 package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'debconf-i18n' missing; assuming pack
age has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'coreutils' missing; assuming package
 has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'zlib1g:amd64' missing; assuming pack
age has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnpth0:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcrypt1:amd64' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3' missing; assuming package h
as no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'systemd' missing; assuming package h
as no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libidn2-0:amd64' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcom-err2:amd64' missing; assuming
 package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'binutils' missing; assuming package 
has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'file' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libassuan0:amd64' missing; assuming 
package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgomp1:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'diffutils' missing; assuming package
 has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'bzip2' missing; assuming package has
 no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libldap-common' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'ubuntu-keyring' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libaudit-common' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgcc-s1:amd64' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtext-wrapi18n-perl' missing; assu
ming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libhcrypto4-heimdal:amd64' missing; 
assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsemanage-common' missing; assumin
g package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libheimntlm0-heimdal:amd64' missing;
 assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libseccomp2:amd64' missing; assuming
 package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsystemd0:amd64' missing; assuming
 package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcap2:amd64' missing; assuming pac
kage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'debconf' missing; assuming package h
as no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libfakeroot:amd64' missing; assuming
 package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gcc' missing; assuming package has n
o files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'dpkg-dev' missing; assuming package 
has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsasl2-modules-db:amd64' missing; 
assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'tzdata' missing; assuming package ha
s no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fakeroot' missing; assuming package 
has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'update-motd' missing; assuming packa
ge has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgcc-9-dev:amd64' missing; assumin
g package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'perl-base' missing; assuming package
 has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libselinux1:amd64' missing; assuming
 package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'dirmngr' missing; assuming package h
as no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'ca-certificates' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'hostname' missing; assuming package 
has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libasan5:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gcc-10-base:amd64' missing; assuming
 package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpcre3:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcap-ng0:amd64' missing; assuming 
package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'perl' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libwind0-heimdal:amd64' missing; ass
uming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'ncurses-base' missing; assuming pack
age has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libglib2.0-data' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgnutls30:amd64' missing; assuming
 package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpam0g:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgssapi3-heimdal:amd64' missing; a
ssuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'make' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libmpfr6:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnupg-l10n' missing; assuming packag
e has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libapt-pkg6.0:amd64' missing; assumi
ng package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'bash-completion' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgmp10:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpython3.8:amd64' missing; assumin
g package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'init-system-helpers' missing; assumi
ng package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libdbus-1-3:amd64' missing; assuming
 package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'dbus' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'xz-utils' missing; assuming package 
has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-gi' missing; assuming packag
e has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'sed' missing; assuming package has n
o files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libquadmath0:amd64' missing; assumin
g package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'shared-mime-info' missing; assuming 
package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libp11-kit0:amd64' missing; assuming
 package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libaudit1:amd64' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'bsdmainutils' missing; assuming pack
age has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libmpc3:amd64' missing; assuming pac
kage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gzip' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'systemd-timesyncd' missing; assuming
 package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libatomic1:amd64' missing; assuming 
package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libuuid1:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'patch' missing; assuming package has
 no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgdbm-compat4:amd64' missing; assu
ming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'util-linux' missing; assuming packag
e has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gir1.2-glib-2.0:amd64' missing; assu
ming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpcre2-8-0:amd64' missing; assumin
g package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'g++-9' missing; assuming package has
 no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libncursesw6:amd64' missing; assumin
g package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libdpkg-perl' missing; assuming pack
age has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsasl2-2:amd64' missing; assuming 
package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'dpkg' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libroken18-heimdal:amd64' missing; a
ssuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libc6:amd64' missing; assuming packa
ge has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gpg-wks-server' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libudev1:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libubsan1:amd64' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsepol1:amd64' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64' missing; a
ssuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'g++' missing; assuming package has n
o files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnettle7:amd64' missing; assuming 
package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3.8-minimal' missing; assuming
 package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'passwd' missing; assuming package ha
s no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'findutils' missing; assuming package
 has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mount' missing; assuming package has
 no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'dmsetup' missing; assuming package h
as no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'sensible-utils' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'uuid-runtime' missing; assuming pack
age has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gpgv' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcrypt-dev:amd64' missing; assumin
g package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libmount1:amd64' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'cpp' missing; assuming package has n
o files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libattr1:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gpgconf' missing; assuming package h
as no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'sysvinit-utils' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnupg' missing; assuming package has
 no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtasn1-6:amd64' missing; assuming 
package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'build-essential' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'cpp-9' missing; assuming package has
 no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libperl5.30:amd64' missing; assuming
 package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libc6-dev:amd64' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcryptsetup12:amd64' missing; assu
ming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libisl22:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64' missing
; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'netbase' missing; assuming package h
as no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-minimal' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'debianutils' missing; assuming packa
ge has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mawk' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libmpdec2:amd64' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libjson-c4:amd64' missing; assuming 
package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libdebconfclient0:amd64' missing; as
suming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'base-files' missing; assuming packag
e has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libbinutils:amd64' missing; assuming
 package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpython3.8-stdlib:amd64' missing; 
assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libbz2-1.0:amd64' missing; assuming 
package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libc-dev-bin' missing; assuming pack
age has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3.8' missing; assuming package
 has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsemanage1:amd64' missing; assumin
g package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'openssl' missing; assuming package h
as no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libbsd0:amd64' missing; assuming pac
kage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgpg-error-l10n' missing; assuming
 package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-lib2to3' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'base-passwd' missing; assuming packa
ge has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl' missing; 
assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'readline-common' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpam-runtime' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libdb5.3:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxml2:amd64' missing; assuming pac
kage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcc1-0:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libblkid1:amd64' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libstdc++6:amd64' missing; assuming 
package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblocale-gettext-perl' missing; ass
uming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gpg' missing; assuming package has n
o files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblsan0:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'dash' missing; assuming package has 
no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libitm1:amd64' missing; assuming pac
kage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libkmod2:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpython3-stdlib:amd64' missing; as
suming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libheimbase1-heimdal:amd64' missing;
 assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgdbm6:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtinfo6:amd64' missing; assuming p
ackage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gcc-9-base:amd64' missing; assuming 
package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libalgorithm-merge-perl' missing; as
suming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnupg-utils' missing; assuming packa
ge has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu' missing; 
assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'login' missing; assuming package has
 no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtsan0:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libkrb5-26-heimdal:amd64' missing; a
ssuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 85609 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-software_3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-software (3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.0) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gnome-software-plugin-snap.
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-software-plugin-snap_3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.0_amd64
.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-software-plugin-snap (3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.0) ...
Setting up gnome-software (3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.0) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Setting up gnome-software-plugin-snap (3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.0) ...
```

Comment: Not sure how you got into this state. Take a look at this solution on serverfault. It looks to resolve the issue with all these warnings. https://serverfault.com/a/430712/117482

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have tried some commands but nothing have worked for me.